# How can I diagnose jerky mouse movement for no reason?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse

Windows 7, just bought 3 new wireless USB mice.   Plugged one into each computer that they were intended for and on one machine it is very jerky.  It stops responding for 10-15 seconds at a time and then will jump wildly all of the screen.  Clicks are delayed and end up on the wrong thing.  Completely unusable.

Tried the other mice from the batch, same on all 3.    All 3 work properly on a different machine.

On the problem machine, if I boot up in safe mode the problem goes away.   But in normal mode its unusable.   In normal mode if I have absolutely nothing running and the system is idle, then the mouse is ALMOST usable moving it around the desktop.  But the moment I have anything going it becomes unusable.

The driver in use is mouclass.sys and mouhid.sys version 6.1.7600.16385
It is exactly the same driver on the computers that work and the one that doesnt.

How can I diagnose what is causing the problem on the one that isnt working?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the Mouse driver is the newest driver. Then from an Admin Command prompt, run SFC /SCANNOW. When it is done, restart and test.  Also update BIOS, Chipset and Video Drivers to see if video is causing the issue.

Comment: If you have any USB extension cable around, try to plug the receiver into that and place the receiver as close to your mouse pad as possible. Otherwise, move your PC box temporarily to within 12 inches of the moue pad.